# Why Socket bind not work as expected while tun network running?

Tags: bind, tun

environment :windows
work cases.
socket bind nic1 => get external ip => work => confirm ! I got the external ip for nic1.
socket bind nic2 => get external ip => work => confirm ! I got the external ip for nic2.

both nic(s) have default route, and nic2 has lower metric.

how ever, when I run tun.

tun was configure has lowest metric and also has default route.
socket bind nic1 => get external ip => not work！
socket bind nic2 => get external ip => not work!

I readed more informations and all says the source ip can not chooose ougoing network nic,
but why it works without tun.

I am confusing , thank advance for any help.